# What data store should I use for storing and querying a billion small (~2kb) JSON documents?

Tags: database-recommendation, json, document-oriented

I'm trying to figure out which database to use for storing and querying on ~1 billion JSON documents about the size of 2KB each. About 2 TB of data.

Nature of JSON documents:

- 3 types of documents (structure is loosely defined)
- Nested, multi level, sparse

Things that I'm looking for are:

- High throughput
- Secondary indexes support
- Queries over JSON

Nice to haves:

- SQL like query interface

Things I'm looking at:

- Cassandra
- Storing JSON in Postgres
- Riak
- HBase

If more details I missed regarding usage or the data I missed that would help make the decision, please let me know

Comment: What do your billion documents represent?

Comment: The number of shopping list questions found on this site :|

Comment: I just always wonder if million+ is projected growth, or real.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Real estate data, it's real, currently stored in S3.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Please let me know if there's a better place to ask these questions. Or how to put this in a better way for this to be useful.